# Javascript date parse why

Tags: javascript, date

Can someone please update my understanding on javascripts new Date('') parse?

For example, why is this:

```
var _date = new Date('2016-10-15');
```

equal to

```
_date = Fri Oct 14 2016 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time) {}
```

and not equal to

```
Oct 15 2016
```

If you use moment.js:

```
var _testdate = moment('2016-10-15').toDate();

_testdate = Sat Oct 15 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time) {}
```

Comment: The date string you passed in is interpreted as an ISO UTC date, so it's 7 hours ahead of you. When you get the string back, that's done in local time.

Comment: If you wake up early and try your code again, it'll work fine :)

Comment: So then how do you make it so it's not interpreted as UTC and to act like the moment.js? I'm very relativistic to myself. I know your time is not the same as my time especially approaching the speed of light but I don't care about you :P

Comment: @Watson—you can't. That behaviour is specified in ECMA-262, to do anything else would be non–compliant with the language specification. If you want to read about why that decision was made, see [*Date Time String Format: default time zone difference from ES5 not web-compatible*](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/87).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, contrary to ISO 8601, date–only forms like '2016-10-15' are treated as UTC by the date constructor and Date.parse, whereas libraries like moment.js are consistent with ISO 8601 and treat them as local.

So since your system is set to UTC-0700, '2016-10-15' is treated as 2016-10-15T00:00:00Z (i.e. UTC+0000), which is 2016-10-14 17:00:00 in your local time zone.

Comment: And there is no overriding functions or variables you can pass to the Date construct to override this behavior? Is it possible to form the string in such a way to not be a date only form but result in a date only form?

Comment: @Watson— no and yes. A Date object is just a time value (ms from the epoch), nothing else. Parsing of ISO 8601 extended format strings is specified in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.parse). Any other parsing is implementation dependent, hence the **strong** recommendation to always parse manually. If using a library, always pass the format to parse, never leave it to chance.